# How to execute function on Parallel.ForEach?

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

I'm trying to:

```
Parallel.ForEach(listOfNames, name => DoSometingWithName(name));
```

while VS asks me to convert method to group, while i can't since this method is used from other places as well. So i don't want to copy paste the code around.

Is there a way to ?

Comment: The code you wrote compiles perfectly well. Could you please show more code + write the full error message you get from compiler?

Comment: Well it is probably ReSharper causing this issue...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Caused by ReSharper thus guys without it never seen this message. I thought it was compiler error.

Elegant work around would be:

```
Parallel.ForEach(listOfNames, DoSometingWithName);
```

Not sure it is more readable though.

Comment: Rather than passing a function which just calls a function, it just passes the function instead. Might be slightly more efficient as there is one less method call.

Comment: This is not a workaround. This is what ReSharper would do if you let him quick fix issue for you by pressing Alt-Enter

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean, but did you search this syntax?

```
Parallel.ForEach(listOfNames, name =>
{
//Place your code here.
 DoSometingWithName(name);
});
```

Comment: Can you post the complete warn message ? this code works at my side without any warning..

 Parallel.ForEach(source, currentString =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(currentString);
                }
            );

Comment: How is "DoSomethingWithName" defined ? it is not a property , is it ? ;)

Comment: DoSomethingWithName is void method.